# Como usar o datepicker do bootstrap para desabilitar algumas datas

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

Eu prciso que depois de uma certa data escolhida pelo usuario, todas as datas a frente fiquem desabilitadas para escolha, tentei o uso de maxDate, mas nao tem efeito algum, consegui desabilitar algumas data usando o disableDate mas nao encontro muito sobre como usá-lo, acabo vendo mais o uso do maxDate que nao esta funcionando pra mim.

eu tenho uma funçao que é chamada quando o usuário clica em uma data q é essa

limitDate() {
     $( "#final_date" ).datepicker({ datesDisabled: ['+m'] });
  }

e onde inicializo meu datepicker esta assim:

```
  activeDate() {
$("#initial_date").datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  startView: "days",
  minViewMode: "days",
  language: 'pt-BR'
});
$("#final_date").datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
  startView: "days",
  minViewMode: "days",
  language: 'pt-BR',
  datesDisabled: this.disabledDates
});
```

}

Alguem pode me ajudar no que estou errando por favor

Answer (score 0):

Basta setar o `endDate` para `+0d`:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',
        endDate: '+0d',
        autoclose: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Link para thread em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20964218/how-to-restrict-bootstrap-date-picker-from-future-date